# convert a single drive btrfs disk into a RAID1 with a second disk

Tags: raid, btrfs

I am running btrfs 4.15.1 on a fresh ubuntu 18.04 server. I have a small hardrive which for `/` and a large disk for documents served to my colleagues in our office via samba. That data drive is used entirely for this, has been created by `mkfs.btrfs /deb/sdb/` and is mounted to `/mnt/data/`.

Further down the road I want to add a second harddisk and convert the singledrive data disk into a RAID1 (data & metadata I guess). Would the commands below achieve that goal?

```
btrfs device add /dev/sdc /mnt/data
btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt
```

would I have to do a `mkfs.btrfs /dev/sdc/` before adding the new harddrive to the system?

Answer (score 14):

Btrfs will create the filesystem for you. Before you add the device, it should look like this:

```
$ sudo btrfs filesystem show
  Label: none  uuid: 14736aed-faa3-4f03-819e-24369e9bb34f
           Total devices 1 FS bytes used 384.00KiB
           devid    1 size 20.00GiB used 2.02GiB path /dev/sdb
```

When adding the device (if there is a existing partition table you need the `-f` option, it will overwrite the partition table) it will look like this:

```
$ sudo btrfs device add -f /dev/sdc /mnt/data
$ sudo btrfs filesystem show
  Label: none  uuid: 14736aed-faa3-4f03-819e-24369e9bb34f
          Total devices 2 FS bytes used 384.00KiB
          devid    1 size 20.00GiB used 2.02GiB path /dev/sdb
          devid    2 size 20.00GiB used 0.00B path /dev/sdc
```

Then start the balancing process:

```
$ sudo btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /mnt/data
  Done, had to relocate 4 out of 4 chunks
```

Comment: thanks, even though starting your response with a general `no, ...` while you confirm a large part of the method mentioned in the question has confused me a little on first sight though. - anyway thanks :-)

Comment: @vrms  sorry for that... but you only ask for the filesystem on /dev/sdc ;-)

Comment: it's fine. I have recovered from the shock :-)

Comment: just a note: the balance step can take time if the first unit is already filled with data, since the files will be mirrored